# How to create Dataframe form presto db table of Array Data type column using spark

Tags: java, postgresql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, presto

I am trying to create spark Dataframe from presto db table which has few columns as Array DataType.
I tried multiple ways but I am getting same exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported type ARRAY
```

Approach 1:(By casting column in json) -Getting null value it is not throwing any exception

```
select json_format(cast(customtags as json)) as customtags from table;
```

Approach 2: (by casting it to String in select query itself) same exception

Approach 3: (By adding custom schema) : Throwing same Error

```
StructType custSchema =  DataTypes.createStructType(
                new StructField[] { 
                        DataTypes.createStructField("customtags", DataTypes.createArrayType(
                                DataTypes.createStructType(
                                        new StructField[]{
                                                DataTypes.createStructField("name", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                                                DataTypes.createStructField("value", DataTypes.StringType, true)
                                        }
                                )
                        ), true)
                        });
Dataset<Row> stgTblDF = sparksession
            .read()
            .format("jdbc")
            .option("driver", "io.prestosql.jdbc.PrestoDriver")
            .option("url","url")
            .option("user", prestoCredentials.getUsername())
            .option("password", prestoCredentials.getPassword())
            .option("query", "select customtags from table").schema(custSchema).load();
```

Approach 4: (By casting as a string in custom schema) But same Exception

```
Properties connectionProperties = new Properties();
    connectionProperties.put("user", prestoCredentials.getUsername());
    connectionProperties.put("password", prestoCredentials.getPassword());
    connectionProperties.put("driver", "io.prestosql.jdbc.PrestoDriver");
    connectionProperties.put("customSchema", "customtags STRING");
    
    Dataset<Row> stgTblDF = sparksession.read().jdbc("jdbc:presto://url","(select customtags from table)", connectionProperties);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
select json_format(cast(customtags as json)) as customtags from table;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).